# Inform java client about server exception/error in grpc

Tags: java, exception, kotlin, grpc

I'm new to the grpc thing and I have build a grpc client/server structure in Java (Client) and Kotlin (Server) The communication works so far. The client is able to trigger the routes defined in the .proto file. I start the server with the following code:

```
class GrpcServer() {
    private var server: Server? = null
    private val logger = Logger.getLogger(GrpcServer::class.java.name)

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    internal fun start(system: ActorSystem) {

        val port = 12345
        server = ServerBuilder.forPort(port)
            .addService(MyServiceImpl(system))
            .build()
            .start()

        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Server started, listening on {0}", port)


        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(object : Thread() {
            override fun run() {
                System.err.println("*** shutting down gRPC server since JVM is shutting down")
                this@GrpcServer.stop()
                System.err.println("*** server shut down")
            }
        })
    }

    private fun stop() {
        server?.shutdown()
    }

    @Throws(InterruptedException::class)
    internal fun blockUntilShutdown() {
            server?.awaitTermination()
    }
}
```

My problem now is when the client connects to this server I don't know how to route exceptions/errors to the client occuring at the class which implements the service methods. For example one message stream is

`rpc getDocuments(stream DocumentsRequest) returns (stream DocumentResponse) {}`

If no exception occurs everything works fine and as expected but an exception while handling the getDocuments service method at the server wont be noticed by the client. For the client, even tho everything is surrounded by try/catch, it is as if nothin happend but it is necessary that the client get informed about the occuring exceptions at the server. The only thing which the client registers is when the server gets completely shut down. So ideally if a NullPOinterException occurs at the server I want that the client gets it too and can handle it with a try/catch

I hope s.o. can help me and if necessary I can post more code

Comment: Exceptions within grpc callbacks should cause the client to receive an UNKNOWN status (and no more information). If you don't see that then you are probably doing processing in separate threads and will need to propagate that yourself. The code snippet here isn't all that helpful, since the implementation of MyServiceImpl is what really matters.